# jQuery submit() vc click() on Modal Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a form inside a Bootstrap Modal, 2 text inputs and a submit button. I want to  send the form data to a Laravel Controller without refreshing current page (where Modal appears) .

First, I used jQuery click() function, and it did what I expect (data sent, Controller executed , returned JSON, and evaluated JSON with success/error rules, and no refresh) .

When I changed the code to jQuery submit() function, data was sent, Controller executed it, return JSON, BUT now browser shows the JSON plain text. No code inside success/error was executed.

Why this different behavior between this 2 functions happens ?

JS -  with click() :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){


        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/question') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#form_pergunta').serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                $('#form_pergunta')[0].reset();
                $('#myModal_Pergunte').modal('hide');
                msgbox_Text = "Sua pergunta foi incluída com sucesso!" ;
                $("#msgbox_alertmsg").append(msgbox_Text);
                $('#myModal_MsgBox').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

JS - with submit():

the same above, but change

```
 $('button#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e)
```

to

```
$('#form_pergunta').submit(function(e)
```

HTML

```
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal_Pergunte" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

        <form method="POST"  action="{{ url('/question')}}" id="form_pergunta">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="formGroupTextArea">What is your question? </label>
             <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupTextArea" placeholder="Faça sua pergunta utilizando até 250 caracteres." rows="8" maxlength="250" name="form_question" required></textarea>
             <h6 class="float-right pt-1 text-muted" id="count_message"></h6>

         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="formGroupInputUrl">Link opcional</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupInputUrl" placeholder="Caso deseje, inclua um link que faça referência a pergunta" name="form_url" maxlength="250">
         </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_submit" id="ajaxSubmit" >Submit</button>
     </div>

     </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you share both options code. The issue could be in many places.

Comment: Both are equal, except but the function used: `$('button#ajaxSubmit').**click**(function(e)` ... to `$('button#ajaxSubmit').**submit**(function(e){`

Comment: Can you please share your html

Comment: Sure, just edited the question.

Comment: I believe I just found an "error" . Previously, the '<input>' was an '<button>' . So , the jQuery '$('button#ajaxSubmit')' targeting the previous '<button>'  should also changed to '$('input#ajaxSubmit')' or '$('#ajaxSubmit')' , right?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the submit event handler to your `form` HTML element, not to the button, because it is the `form` element who throws the submit event, not the button. So you should be doing something like this:

```
$('#form_pergunta').submit(function(e) { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
$('button#ajaxSubmit').submit(function(e){ ... }
```

Comment: f-CJ, I tested both , the different behavior  continues. Important to note that with both functions the form is submited and executed by Controller. The problem appears with return/response treatment.